# cant get any trades to appear on backtesting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

hello i wanted to make it so the trade has a stop loss of 13% and a take profit of 26% when a trade occurs and only have one position open at a time. but when i add the code to the chart no trades appear on the backtesting. thank you

heres the code.

```
// Buy when EMA 5 crosses above EMA 13 within 11 bars of a demand zone    
buy_condition = ta.crossover(ema5, ema13) and ta.barssince(l) <= 11 and strategy.opentrades==0

if buy_condition        
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)        
    strategy.close("Buy", stop_loss=strategy.position_avg_price * 0.87, take_profit=strategy.position_avg_price * 1.26)    

// Sell when EMA 5 crosses below EMA 13 within 11 bars of a supply zone
sell_condition = ta.crossunder(ema5, ema13) and ta.barssince(h) <= 11 and strategy.opentrades==0

if sell_condition        
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)        
    strategy.close("Sell", stop_loss=strategy.position_avg_price * 1.13, take_profit=strategy.position_avg_price * 0.74)
```

the (l) and (h) are defined in the code so i dont think they are the problem. i can add more of the script if this isnt enough once again thank you.

Comment: This is generated code, isn't it?

Comment: Also, how are you able to add this to your chart? This code won't even compile.

Comment: Ive been trying to do it myself but I am having a hard to I watched kioseff trading on YouTube and tried to combine what he was saying with what other YouTuber do to fit what’s needed but I am having a hard time. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

There is no `stop_loss` or `take_profit` arguments in `strategy.close()`.

`strategy.close()` closes positions conditionally. You want to close your position based on price. Therefore you should use `strategy.exit()`.

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0)  // If you are in a long position
    strategy.exit("LE", "Buy", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * 0.87, limit=strategy.position_avg_price * 1.26)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)  // If you are in a short position
    strategy.exit("SE", "Sell", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * 1.13, limit=strategy.position_avg_price * 0.74)
```